# Error in Multinominal regression: "NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments"

Tags: r, regression, na

I'm doing Multinominal regression with the help of [this site](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/mlogit.htm).

I got error while doing:

```
    > dses1 <- data.frame(ses = c("Cluster1", "Cluster2", "Cluster3"), GDP = mean(data.mod$GDP.z))
    > dses1
           ses         GDP
    1 Cluster1 -0.03853141
    2 Cluster2 -0.03853141
    3 Cluster3 -0.03853141

    > predict(results, newdata = dses1, "probs")  
    NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments
```

I've done regression as follows

```
    results <- multinom(data.mod$baseline~data.mod$cluster+data.mod$GDP.z+data.mod$WGI.z,data=data.mod)
```

Dataset is like this:

```
    > head(data.mod)
       cluster  type       GDP.z     WGI.z baseline
    1 Cluster3 Type1 -0.15927872 0.0750328    Type1
    2 Cluster3 Type1  0.18363900 0.1066325    Type1
    3 Cluster1 Type1  1.58636819 0.0750328    Type1
    4 Cluster3 Type1 -0.27892696 0.7034406    Type1
    5 Cluster3 Type1 -0.37910360 0.6864063    Type1
    6 Cluster2 Type1 -0.09978649 0.0750328    Type1
```

I already checked [this stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21663945/how-to-use-predict-with-multinom-with-intercept-in-r), but got the same error again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use predict, it needs to match up column names exactly with those shown by `coef(results)`. Since you unnecessarily left the table name prefix on all your variable names, that's probably what's causing the error. Try

```
results <- multinom(baseline~cluster + GDP.z + WGI.z, data=data.mod)
```

Also you seem to be missing `WGI.z` form your `newdata` (Since it was in the model, it has to be there). So your `newdata` should be

```
dses1 <- data.frame(cluster = c("Cluster1", "Cluster2", "Cluster3"), 
    GDP.z = mean(data.mod$GDP.z),
    WGI.z = mean(data.mod$WGI.z)
)
```

and those names should match the names in your formula so you should be all set.

Comment: @user2978524 If it works, please consider clicking the checkmark by this answer to accept it. That's how StackOverflow works.

Comment: All right. Thanks.

I wonder if you know a good way to visualize the results. The [webpage](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/mlogit.htm) can't use for my case, since there are two control variables:GDP and WGI.

Comment: @user2978524 Comments are not a good place to ask new questions. feel free to start a new post if you have a different question. Although, broad, opinion-based questions like "how do i visualize this data" are frowned upon on this site. It should be a specific programming question.